# JBoss Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: java, jboss, velocity

I have an application that needs to be deployed in JBoss 6.0.0 and I am using Eclipse Mars. My system variable points to Java 1.6, from build path I've selected Java 1.6 and also, JBoss is using Java 1.6. My problem is that when trying to deploy the app to JBoss the following error

`[org.jboss.detailed.classloader.ClassLoaderManager] Unexpected error during load of:com.xservice.java.velocity.VelocityLoader: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/xservice/java/velocity/VelocityLoader : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0`.

I don't have any idea how to handle this considering the given settings.

Comment: in which jar is `VelocityLoader` class present?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was fixed by changing the Java version from Project Facets(it was 1.8 instead of 1.6). Thanks go to Sanjeev Saha. 
[Project facets screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEQWG.png)

Answer (score 1):

Please locate the Jar which contains the class `com.xservice.java.velocity.VelocityLoader`.

This class is compiled with JDK 8. The class file version for Java SE 8 is 52.0 as per http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-compatibility-guide-2156366.html Your JVM is Java 6. You may not be able to run a Java class compiled with JDK 8.0 by JVM 6.0. This is the reason you are getting 'Unsupported major.minor version 52.0'

My suggestion is using a Jar which contains classes compiled by JDK 6.0.

Comment: The `com.xservice.java.velocity.VelocityLoader` is not in a jar. It's one of my classes, so that sould be compiled with 1.6.

Comment: Could you please tell me what you see when you type `java -version` and `javac -version` on the command prompt?

Comment: Hi @i.olteanu most likely you compiled the said class with JDK 8.0. This is reason JAVA 6.0 run time is giving you  `Unsupported major.minor version 52.0`.

Comment: java - version : `java version "1.6.0_24"`
javac -version : `javac 1.6.0_24`
@Sanjeev : It's compiled by eclipse, and I have selected java 1.6 from the project's Build Path.

Comment: Please tell me what you see when you type `javap -verbose com.xservice.java.velocity.VelocityLoader | findstr "major"`?

Comment: Major version: 52. How can this be?

Comment: This means that this class has been compiled with JDK 8.0. But one question if your system needs at least JAVA 7.0 in order to run `Eclipse Mars`.

Comment: I have JDK 8.0 installed and set eclipse.ini to start using JDK 8.0.

Comment: In that case Eclipse using JDK 8.0 to compile your class. Sure.

Comment: You can solve your problem by compiling the Java files outside Eclipse.